# Residues of $z^{\alpha}\Re(z)$ and $z^{2\alpha + 1}\Re(z^{2})$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

For the function $z^{\alpha}\Re(z)$ where $\Re(z)$ is a rational function with a zero of at least two at infinity, at most a simple pole at the origin and $0<\alpha<1$.

How do we show that the residues of $z^{\alpha}\Re(z)$ in the whole plane is the same as the residues of $z^{2\alpha + 1}\Re(z^{2})$ in the upper half plane?

This is based on an extract of a paragraph from Ahlfors Complex Analysis

Comment: If $f(z)$ is a rational and $a\in (0,1)$ then $g(z)=z^a f(z)$ has a branch point at $z=0$ and it is locally meromorphic on $\Bbb{C}^*$ so the residue at its poles depend on the chosen branch, once one branch is given the others are $e^{2i\pi an} g(z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\phi$ is biholomorphic $V\to U$ and $a\in U$ is a **simple pole** of $h$ meromorphic on $U$ then for $z$ close to $a$ $$h(z)=\frac{Res(h(w),a)}{z-a}+O(1)$$ For $s$ close to $b=\phi^{-1}(a)$ $$h(\phi(s))=\frac{Res(h(w),a)}{\phi(s)-a}+O(1)=\frac{Res(h(w),a)}{\phi'(b)(s-b)+O(s-b)^2}+O(1)$$ $$
=\frac{Res(h(w),a)}{\phi'(b)(s-b)}+O(1)$$
thus $$Res(h(\phi(s)),b)=\frac{Res(h(z),a)}{\phi'(b)}$$
It fails if $a$ is a double pole, try with $\phi(s)=1/s, h(z)=1/(z-1)^2$, $h(\phi(s))=1+\frac{2s-1}{(s-1)^2}$ has a non-zero residue at $1$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting.